# generate the ciphertext in different language like Arabic (AES)

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I have this program for encryption and decryption text

after I click encrypt, the encrypted text will be random letters

can I make the generated cipher text in Arabic instead of random English letter?

how can I change the language for the cipher text

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Encrypter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string key, EnValue;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            txtKey.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            key = Convert.ToString(txtKey.Text);
            EnValue = Convert.ToString(txtToEncript.Text);

            if (key != "" && EnValue!="" )
            {

                txtResult.Text=EncryptStringAES(EnValue, key);

            }
            else
            {

                lblResult.Text = "Enter text to Encrypt";
                return;
            }
        }

        private void btnDecript_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               EnValue = Convert.ToString(txtResult.Text);
               key = Convert.ToString(txtKey.Text);


            if (key != "" && EnValue != "")
            {
                txtToEncript.Text = DecryptStringAES(EnValue,key);

            }
            else
            {
                lblResult.Text = "Enter text to Decrypt";
                return;
            }
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        private static byte[] _salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("o6806642kbM7c5");

        public static string EncryptStringAES(string plainText, string sharedSecret)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

            string outStr = null;                       // Encrypted string to return
            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;              // RijndaelManaged object used to encrypt the data.

            try
            {
                // generate the key from the shared secret and the salt
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

                // Create a RijndaelManaged object
                aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
                aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    // prepend the IV
                    msEncrypt.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(aesAlg.IV.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
                    msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                    }
                    outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Label l1 = new Label();
                l1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                l1.Text = "Enter Proper Key value.";
                l1.Show();
                Form1 f = new Form1();
                f.Controls.Add(l1);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
                if (aesAlg != null)
                    aesAlg.Clear();
            }

            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return outStr;
        }


        public static string DecryptStringAES(string cipherText, string sharedSecret)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

            // Declare the RijndaelManaged object
            // used to decrypt the data.
            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = null;

            try
            {
                // generate the key from the shared secret and the salt
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

                // Create the streams used for decryption.                
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    // Create a RijndaelManaged object
                    // with the specified key and IV.
                    aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
                    aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
                    // Get the initialization vector from the encrypted stream
                    aesAlg.IV = ReadByteArray(msDecrypt);
                    // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label l = new Label();
                l.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                l.Text="Enter Proper Key value.";
                l.Show();
                Form1 f = new Form1();
                f.Controls.Add(l);

            }
            finally
            {
                // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
                if (aesAlg != null)
                    aesAlg.Clear();
            }

            return plaintext;
        }

        private static byte[] ReadByteArray(Stream s)
        {
            byte[] rawLength = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            if (s.Read(rawLength, 0, rawLength.Length) != rawLength.Length)
            {
                throw new SystemException("Stream did not contain properly formatted byte array");
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(rawLength, 0)];
            if (s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) != buffer.Length)
            {
                throw new SystemException("Did not read byte array properly");
            }

            return buffer;
        }

        private void btnCpyEncrt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(txtResult.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `ToBase64String`, which maps the binary result to a longer string containing A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, and = characters. You'll need to implement your own mapping from these to Arabic characters because there's no standard that does this.